# Programmatically pass a url to an anonymous proxy like http://www.trycatchme.com

Tags: proxy, anonymous

I'm using .net httpwebrequest &/or webclient class

How can i Progamatically pass a url to an anonymous proxy like http://www.trycatchme.com and get back a result

```
<form method="post" action="/index.php">
    <input id="address_bar" type="text" name="q" value="http://www." onfocus="this.select()" />
    <input id="surf_button" type="image" value="Surf Now" src="images/surfnowbtn.gif"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="hl[include_form]"  value="1"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="hl[remove_scripts]"  value="1"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="hl[accept_cookies]"  value="1"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="hl[show_images]" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hl[show_referer]"  value="1"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="hl[base64_encode]" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hl[strip_meta]"  value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hl[session_cookies]" value="1" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HttpWebRequest.Proxy Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx) might be what you want.